# Adding points to point vector layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, data, point

I have a point layer with multiple data points in QGIS, but I want to add some extra data points to it and adjust some info that we missed because the ground was wet and we needed to go around it.  I can't figure it out.  I would think you would go in edit mode and have an option to add points, but can't find it.

Comment: Is the editing toolbar active? There is an "Add Feature" button.

Comment: The pen icon is greyed out so I can't use it, what can I do?

Answer (score 8):

1. Select your layer from the left-hand layers-list
2. Click on pen icon in the editing toolbar at the top of the screen.  If you can;'t see the right tool bar, right-click on the menu area at the very top of the screen and check 'Digitizing' from the popup menu.  (You can also set a layer to editable by right clicking on the layer in the list or going to the 'Layer' menu item and clicking on the same little pen icon in either location).
3. To add points, click on the 'Add Feature' tool (icon of three red dots).

You are now good to go.  Points will be added wherever you click so long as your layer is highlighted in the layers-list.  You can save your edits at any time by clicking on the little disk icon in the Digitizing toolbar (between the pen icon and three dots icon).  When you are finished, toggle editting off by clicking on the pen icon again.  If you toggle digitizing off without saving, you will be prompted to save your edits.

Answer (score 2):

if you can't enable editing then maybe your data is saved as geojson or kml, you can save it as a shapefile (shp) with QGIS and load it again this way the edits can be enabled from the tool bar ( the little pen ) and you can add the data you wanted.