# Create points on a map by clicking and exporing it to CSV?

Tags: point, software-recommendations

I have been for a while looking for an app or website where I could display a map on screen and create a list of points over it by just clicking and adding them.

I'd like to export this list in CSV format, like:

```
ID, LONG, LAT
1, xx.xxx, yy.yyy
2, xx.xxx, yy.yyy
```

I decided to ask here because I still can't find an easy way to do this that wouldn't involve coding it by myself.

Comment: What software do you have available? Do you want to do this in a program or via a browser? Windows, Mac, Linux, Android, other? You could add placemarks in Google Earth and then export to CSV.. though you might need to code that part; if you google KML to CSV there are many sites that say they can convert your data.

Comment: Im using Linux and I don't care if it's web or an application. If it's web it may be easier but I just need to create points by clicking and exporting. The thing is that I will have to add many (more than 1000) points and most of the web-apps out there require many steps to add just ONE point... maybe I will really end up coding it by myself if there is a way to get the coords of they mouse X,Y position over a google map..

Comment: You can use QGIS, create a point shapefile, add Google imagery, insert all your points (1000 is fine, you'd probably get nearer 1 million before you hit any sort of limit) then calculate the X and Y coordinates into the table and export to CSV... all interactive with no scripting. Does that sound like something you'd be interested in doing? BTW QGIS is open source, thereby free, just download and install for Windows, Linux or Mac.

Comment: http://geojson.io  makes a GeoJSON file,
http://www.convertcsv.com/geojson-to-csv.htm   then use this to make a csv.. No coding involved.

Comment: @geojson.io thanks that's a terrific web app. I just wish I could have a key binding to add new points without having to click on the marker icon each time. Congrats for that app it's a goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/) for this task, it's open source and fairly easy to use; there are [tutorials](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/trainingmaterial/index.html) to help you to get started. After installing QGIS and before you start locate the [OpenLayers plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/openlayers_plugin/) (or according to [Adding Basemaps from Google or Bing in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20191/adding-basemaps-from-google-or-bing-in-qgis) use [QuickMapServices](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/)) and add it to QGIS.

Firstly [create a new point shapefile](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/create_new_vector.html), use the coordinate reference system (CRS) of WGS84 (EPSG:4326), this is compatible with Google.

Secondly add your new shapefile to QGIS (click Add Data button)

Add Google Imagery using the plugin and [set your canvas CRS](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html) to Web Mercator (EPSG:3857) and make sure you set 'project on the fly'.

[Add your points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23736/adding-points-to-point-vector-layer-using-qgis).

[Add new fields](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html) of LAT and LON for your points' location.

[Calculate the XY values](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7199/how-do-i-calculate-the-latitude-and-longitude-of-points-using-qgis).

[Export your table to CSV](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135801/how-to-export-attribute-table-to-excel-from-qgis).

Remove unnecessary fields with Excel (or similar).

It sounds like an involved process but isn't really, read the tutorials linked and it should be quite clear and straightforward and afterwards you'll have a basic understanding of QGIS which may help in the future to create maps etc.